# tcl - when to use package+namespace vs interp?

Tags: tcl

I'm just starting with TCL and trying to get my head around how to best define and integrate modules. There seem to be much effort put into the package+namespace concept, but from what I can tell interp is more powerful and lean for every thinkable scenario. In particular when it comes to hiding and renaming procedures, but also the lack of creep in the global namespace. The only reason to use package+namespaces seem to be because "once upon a time Sun said so".

When should I ever use package+namespace instead of interp?

Comment: To conserve memory in large applications, when you have performance concerns with the construction and destruction of interpreters (more costly than namespace management). I'd recommend reading the documentation and based on what your application requirements are, make your decision. Applications are so broad that it is unwise to summarily dismiss `interp` or `namespace`. In general, `interp` creates a slave interpreter managed by the master `interp`. Each interp has its own namespace. So you could be wasting resources by creating interps. But your requirements should determine what you use.

Answer (score 3):

Namespaces and packages work together. Interpreters are something else.

A **namespace** is a small scale naming context in Tcl. It can contain commands, variables and other namespaces. You can refer to entities in a namespace via either local names (`foo`) or via qualified names (`bar::foo`); if a qualified name starts with `::`, it is relative to the (interpreter-)global namespace, and can be used to refer to its command or variable from anywhere in the interpreter. (FWIW, the TclOO object system builds extensively on top of namespaces; there is one namespace per object.)

A **package** is a high-level concept for a bunch of code supplied by some sort of library. Packages have abstract names (the name do *not* have to correspond to how the library's implementation is stored on disk) and a distinct version; you can ask for a particular version if necessary, though most of the time you don't bother. Packages can be implemented by multiple mechanisms, but they almost all come down to `source`ing some number of Tcl scripts and `load`ing some number of DLLs. Almost all packages declare commands, and they conventionally are encouraged to put those commands in a namespace with the same general name as the package. However, quite a few older packages do not do this for various reasons, mostly to do with compatibility with existing code.

An **interpreter** is a security context in Tcl. By default, Tcl creates one interpreter (plus another if it sets up the console window in `wish`). Named entities in one interpreter are completely distinct from named entities in another interpreter with a few key exceptions:

1. Channels have common names across all interpreters. This means that an interpreter can talk about channels owned by another interpreter, but merely being able to mention its name doesn't give permission to access the channel. (The `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` channels are shared by default.)
2. The `interp alias` command can be used to make alias commands, which are such that invoking a command (the alias) in one interpreter can cause a command (the implementation) in another interpreter to be called, with all arguments safely passed over. This allows one interpreter to expose whatever special calls it wants another interpreter to access without losing control, but it is up to the implementation of those commands to act safely on those arguments.

A **safe interpreter** is one with the unsafe commands of Tcl profiled out by default. (That's things like `open`, `socket`, `source`, `load`, `cd`, etc.) The parent interpreter that created the safe child interpreter can use the alias mechanism to add in exactly the functionality desired; it's very much analogous to an OS system call except you can easily make your own application-specific ones.

Tcl's threading package is designed to create **one interpreter per thread** (and the aliasing mechanism does not work across threads). That means that there's very little in the way of shared resources by default, and inter-thread communication is done via queued message passing.

---

In general, packages are required at most once per interpreter and are how you are recommended to access most third-party functionality. Namespaces are fairly lightweight and are used for all sorts of things, and interpreters are considered to be expensive; lots of quite thoroughly production-grade Tcl scripts only ever work with a single interpreter. (Threads are even more expensive than interpreters; it's good practice to match the number of threads you create to the hardware load that you wish to impose, probably through the use of suitable thread pools.)

Comment: Basically, interpreters hardly do any sort of resource sharing but provide substantial safety guarantees, whereas namespaces are just naming scopes used to stop code from accidentally treading on each others toes, which is very useful in a large script. Namespaces are not security devices; interpreters _are_ security devices (and the roots of operations in each user thread in the program).

Comment: Very nice summary. I'll have to look into this threading thing a bit more, seems important. However, can **interp alias** really be that heavy weight compared to namespaces? Is it more than just function-pointers under the hood? And why would any Tcl scripts only work with a single interpreter? Namespaces typically result in more symbols and longer symbol names for any interpreter, so I would excpect namespaces being worse than interpreters. Again, new to this. Be nice to the newbie.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of a module is to provide modular code, i.e. code that can easily be used by applications beyond the module writer's knowledge and control, and that encapsulates their own internals.

Package-namespace- and interpreter-based modules are probably equally good at encapsulation, but it's not as easy to make interpreter-based modules that play well with arbitrary applications (it is of course possible).

My own opinion is that interpreters are application level (I mostly use them for user input and for controlled evaluation), not module level. Both namespaces and packages have their warts, but in most cases they do what is expected of them with a minimum of fuss.

My recommendation is that if you are writing modules for your own benefit and interpreters serve you well, by all means use them. If you write modules that other people are to use, possibly including yourself in 18 months, you should stick with namespaces and packages.

Comment: "_it's not as easy to make interpreter-based modules that play well with arbitrary applications_"? Do you have any simple example? Might be of interest: my view of how interpreter based integration would look like is any script being defined in the global namespace, sourced into a fresh interpreter, and integrated with other modules using alias. The script does not itself create the interpreter.

Comment: @Andreas: no simple example can adequately demonstrate how the complexity of execution increases. Interpreters *are* mainly a mechanism to impede and limit (which is good where this is desirable). Everything that is simple to do with an interpreter can be done even simpler without it, except controlled evaluation. For a user of your module, it being based on an interpreter makes it harder to integrate and considerably harder to test and debug. In contrast, namespaces are designed to make modules easier to use. As for packages, you can't really dispense with them even if you use an interpreter.

Comment: My conclusion is the opposite. Interpreter based integration puts the integrator in control, whereas namespace based puts the integrator dependent on the module provider following a wide list of rules, e.g. good choice of namespace name, limited polution in the global namespace. Those are solid examples of pro interpreters, con namespaces. So far the closest example pro namespaces is when threading (see Donal answer). Programming patterns and experiences are hardly language features (although valuable input).

Comment: @Andreas: if you feel that you as a self-described newbie have a better grasp of this than I have with 18 years of Tcl experience, almost 40 overall with programming, by all means follow your convictions. ;)